# react-router 4 unmounts matching component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an issue where the new react-router 4 unmounts something that I think that it shouldn't.

See the following simple example. Clicking the "Home" link unmounts the Match/Miss in the Root component. Why is that?

```
function Root() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <h1>Example</h1>
        <Match exactly pattern="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/home" />} />
        <Miss component={App} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/home">Home</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <Match pattern="/home" component={Home} />
    </div>
  )
}

function Home() { return (<h1>Home</h1>); }

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
)
```

Run the example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/blacksails/s1fv62vc/

Comment: The `<Miss>` component will be removed in the soon to be released beta. I wouldn't worry too much about `<Miss>` issues right now.

Comment: Why don't you use components, `extends React.Component` to work with the Router?

Comment: @PaulS Thanks for the headsup. Do you know of any issues or other documentation for the reasoning of removing Miss?

Comment: @prosti Because I favour functional style over object orientation.

Comment: @PaulS Ah it seems Miss will be be possible with the Switch and Route(Replaces Match i guess) components combined, right?

Comment: Yes. A "miss" can be the last `<Route>` in a `<Switch>`.

Comment: Just to clarify, it needs not to be the last - it's simply the first matched Route gets rendered by Switch. In the case of a Route without a path, it would always match, but it should follow all Routes with a path